# Options when storing all data in memory doesn't scale

Tags: java, sql, database, nosql

I've written a Java application that users install on there desktop. It crawls websites, storing the data about each page in a LinkedList. The application allows users to view all the pages crawled in a JTable.

This works great for small sites, but doesn't scale very well. Currently users have to allocate more memory (which translates to a -Xmx when starting Java) for larger crawls.

My current thinking is to move to storing all the data in a database, possibly using something like HSQLDB.

Are there any other approaches I should be considering?

Comment: You could use an 'ordinary' (binary?) file for each site/page... the relational approach may not be the right thing to do, but it depends on your concrete implementation.

Comment: How many pages do you need to store, and how fast are you downloading them (rough order of magnitude)? How do you need to query them or look them up? There are lots of possible solutions, but it all depends...

Answer (score 0):

relation db is not a good place to store web page data. could you save pages on disk? i you want to do searching on the crawling results. try the apache lucene searching engine. loading all the results all-in-once in memory is not reasonable. you can paginate the JTable model.,and use soft-reference  to cache some results when pagination.

Answer (score 0):

A relational database is probably the right approach for this case. Reasons:

- It'll enable you to handle larger-than-memory crawls.
- If you keep the link data in separate tables from the considerable larger volumes of page data, you may still be able to fit all your links in memory which will be pretty important from a performance and searching perspective
- It will give you an easy way of persisting crawled data (in case this is needed in the future)
- It's pretty well known / standard technology
- There are good open source database implementation available ([H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) or [JavaDB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html) would probably be my first choices as they are embeddable and written in pure Java)
- The relational features could turn out to be useful, for example queries on link data
- It doesn't sound like you have the data volumes or availability requirements that might push you towards a NoSQL-type solution

Answer (score 0):

You have basically 4 options:

1. Store the data in flat files
2. Store the data in a database
3. Somehow transmit the data to "the cloud" (I have no idea how)
4. Somehow "pare" the data down to the essentials, knowing that you can re-extract the full info when needed

You can also do a variant of 4 to gain some space -- rather than a "rich" object structure, compress each distinct datum into a single String or byte[] or some such that you keep in an array or arraylist vs a linked list.  This can reduce your storage requirements by 2X or more.  Less "object oriented", but sometimes reality intervenes.

Answer (score 0):

Try storing the page data in db4o http://community.versant.com , an object database. Object databases handle complex objects (eg. with lots of siblings) than relational databases.